# Is it possible to control 12v pump only with arduino (no 12V battery)

Tags: arduino, 12v

I want to control a 12V pump with an arduino (it is actually a WeMos D1) and I would like to avoid the use of an external battery (to avoid that they run out of battery without me noticing it). I have seen a lot of options using a 12V battery but I would like to know if it possible to do it without one or it has no sense.

Comment: Would it not be easier to add in a simple detection circuit for when the battery gets low? Either that, or if you don't want to use a battery, use mains? Then just convert to 12V DC? How are you powering the arduino through all this?

Comment: You appear to be asking "can I power stuff without a battery?". The answer is yes; have a power adaptor from mains (lots of 12V options out there).

Comment: if you're not versed in circuitry, get a 12v (cigarette lighter) to USB adapter, like the ones at gas stations, and then you have a place to plug in your wemos. use a relay or logic-level mosfet to turn the pump on and off. use a 12v wall wort to get 12v.

Comment: @dandavis That's under the assumption this is used within a car is it not?

Comment: no, any 12v dc will work just fine. in fact, better than a car's noisy 12v rail. you can pop the cheap case off or use alligator clips to adapt, or solder onto the springs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a 12v pump which runs quite nicely at low speed from 5v.

However, it takes much more current than an Arduino would switch, so would need an external power transistor to switch it, and of course it would need a beefy enough 5v source to drive it. And I'm happy with the low speed, most people would want the 12v pump performance.

If you have a large enough 5v battery, you could use a 5v to 12v boost converter, which might even be enablable directly from the Arduino.

When those alternatives are considered, it's probably far easier to do it the obvious way and use a 12v source, using the regulator internal to the Arduino board to drive that, and using a suitable transistor to switch the pump.

Comment: And what would be the circuit used then?

Comment: for which one? The simplest way? Battery feeds the gnd and DC input of the Arduino. Batt +12 goes to pump. Arduino drives either the gate of a logic level FET, or the base of a Darlington transistor, with its source or emitter connected to gnd. The other pump terminal goes to the drain or collector. Don't forget the anti-parallel diode across the pump, to catch the switch-off transient.

Comment: and for using it with 5V what would be the circuit?

Comment: Jeez, 5v battery to Arduino and boost converter input, boost converter output to pump, Arduino data output to boost converter's control input.

Answer (score 0):

With an arduino alone, No. you will need an external source of DC voltage. it could be either a battery or a DC power supply that plugs into a mains.

As an alternative, you could use your arduino to monitor your battery voltage and turn the pump off if necessary.